# how to put opencart 2.0 customer first name and last name on header?

Tags: opencart2.x

Can anyone please tell me how to put customer's first and last name into the header in OpenCart 2.0?

I am already using this code for OpenCart 1.5.6:

```
<?php echo $this->customer->getFirstName(); ?>
<?php echo $this->customer->getLastName(); ?>
```

But this code is not working for OC 2.0

I am getting this error : `Undefined property: Loader::$customer in header.tpl`

Please help me anyone.

Comment: "But ThisCode Is Not Working" - what error message do you get?

Comment: I Am Getting This Error  : Undefined property: Loader::$customer in header.tpl

Comment: Then please edit your question to include this. Btw I see somebody answered. If the answer is correct, then please press the checkmark.

Comment: Learn how to write. Only a sentence starts with uppercase letter, not each word in the sentence. In OC2.0 there is no longer `$this` nor *registry* available in template, therefore you need to prepare all the data in your controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this error you need to call them in the controller instead of in the template.

In catalog/controller/common/header.php add the following code inside the index() function:

```
$data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
$data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();
```

In catalog/view/theme/your-theme/template/common/header.tpl you can echo the first and last name:

```
echo $customer_firstname;
echo $customer_lastname;
```

Note that it is better not to edit Opencart core files. Instead you can use VQMod to implement the changes in the header controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a solution to add first name last name of logged in user :
1.Go To: catalog/controller/common/header.php

2. Then find public function index () {....
3. Then add the following code:

if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $data['welcome_message'] = sprintf("Welcome %s %s, Enjoy your stay!", $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->customer->getLastName());
}

4. Now go to : catalog/view/theme/YOURTHEME/template/common/header.tpl
5. then put this where you want :