# how to put opencart 2.0 customer name on header?

Tags: opencart

Can Any One Please Tell Me 
how to put opencart 2.0 customer first name and last name on header?

I Am Already Use this Code For Opencart 1.5.6 Working Fine But In 2.0 Getting Error

> $this->customer->getFirstName(); ?> $this->customer->getLastName(); ?>

But ThisCode Is Not Working For 2.0 Version

I Am Getting This Error : Undefined property: Loader::$customer in header.tpl

Please Help Me Any One

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to put opencart 2.0 customer first name and last name on header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430280/how-to-put-opencart-2-0-customer-first-name-and-last-name-on-header)

Comment: Do not post the same question again and again. Instead of this improve your first question if you are not getting the correct answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this error you need to call them in the controller instead of in the template.

In catalog/controller/common/header.php add the following code inside the index() function:

```
$data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
$data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();
```

In catalog/view/theme/your-theme/template/common/header.tpl you can echo the first and last name:

```
echo $customer_firstname;
echo $customer_lastname;
```

Note that it is better not to edit Opencart core files. Instead you can use VQMod to implement the changes in the header controller.

Comment: I need another help also mate... if u dont mine please tell me .. how to redirect same page after login in opencrat 2.0 ? .. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe you can create a new question for it with some more info.